# Save UIButton Change State in Realm Swift 3 with Notification Center

Tags: ios, notifications, swift3, uibutton, realm

I have a button whose sender observes a notification and changes its title after it fires. Before firing, the button title is "A". After firing, the button title is "B".

I am trying to save the changed state in Realm so the user can see that the button's been changed.

The post (firing) notification occurs in another button action that adds a UIView. That subview owns the post notification:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: fireNotification, object: nil)
```

The other add (observer) notification acts on this event when the post is fired:

```
// MARK: - Observe Notification

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: fireNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        print("Notification Observed")

        sender.setTitle("B", for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        sender.isEnabled = false
    }
```

This obviously changes the button state to B. How do I write and save this to my realm? I've tried:

```
// MARK: - Observe Notification

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: fireNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    print("Notification Observed")

      let realm = try! Realm()
      try! realm.write {
        sender.setTitle("B", for: .normal)
        sender.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        sender.isEnabled = false
          } 
      }
```

Should I add something to the object param?

Answer (score 0):

For being able to save data in Realm you need to create your own subclass of `RealmObject` and define it's properties. You can't save state of non-`RealmObjects`.

Please checkout out the docs to learn more about Realm: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: Hey Dmitry, Would you mind giving me an example? Button is not a type Realm supports and thus cannot be used as a property. I tried using Data but that does not work, either. I have tried every permutation from outlets and actions via storyboard to programmatically creating a button, switching on `isSelected` and even using `UIImage(named: "abc")`. I read the docs. There is no example anywhere on custom buttons in tableviews or collectionviews.

Comment: For the record, I am also using Realm Notifications (which are great!) but cannot save state of the selected item at IndexPath, as there is no IndexPath to the button.